# I can not save data to MySQL when is tomcat running

Tags: server, java, mysql

I have `tomcat 7` and `mysql 5.5.46`.

On my tomcat is running simple application which reads data from mysql.

I have another java program that stores data in to mysql.

When running tomcat and java program (desktop app) not saved data and gets stuck.

When I turn off tomcat and start only java program it works correctly (!!) .

Where could it be wrong? It looks like tomcat dared write another application to the database.

Both programs work, they do not have any bug or an error.

Thank you for your advice.

**EDIT:**

In my Java dekstop app I am using `DriverManager` from `java.sql`.

In my Java web app I am using `hibernate`.

My `persisntence.xml` is:

```
<persistence-unit name="org.danekja.edu.pia"  transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/donutek_db"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="true" />

        <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have **default** settings in tomcat and mysql. I did not change anything because it's just learning.

Comment: perhaps your java application and tomcat are writing to the same DB using the same parameters. It is difficult to tell anything if you don't post the details of tomcat configuration and java app db connections and access parameters.

Comment: @ostendali Yes, same db, same parameters, same tables, etc... Ok, I will post more info, wait a minute.

Comment: there is no need to post anything, if it is the same Db using the same parameters how would you expect that working? it is obvious that they will be in conflict with each other. When the DB connection socket is already in use by a primary application it is not possible that such socket can be shared with another application. you can't run 2 apps at the same time writing to the same DB unless you are not using some proper frameworks. It is a simple concept.

Comment: @ostendali Is there any solution how to do this? Desktop application will only run once per day at a time (eg, 1 PM in the morning ).

Comment: if you are using hibernate as framework it is possible to do that. Here someone asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537675/connect-two-or-more-applications-to-the-same-database-using-hibernate you will need to configure second level cache or if you are good with Mysql you can do that from mysql side as well configuring the concurrency on mysql engine. plenty similer posts you can find on stackowerflow

Comment: @ostendali Thank you for the explanation and reference